# Update specific columns in realm model

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to update a specific item in a realm model.

Here is the problem a user logs in and logs the timeIn then at a later time logs back in and adds the timeOut. when this is done using my current code it creates two realm instances instead of one row with both a timeIn and timeOut.

```
@IBAction func saveTimeSheetButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if let timeSheetEntry = self.selectedEmployeeTime{


        do{
            try  self.realm.write {


                let updateTimeSheet = EmployeeTimeSheet()

                updateTimeSheet.timeSheetID = "timeSheetID"

                updateTimeSheet.employeeName = employeeNameLabel.text!
                updateTimeSheet.timeOut = finishTimeLabel.text!
                updateTimeSheet.comments = commentView.text!

                realm.add(updateTimeSheet, update: true)
                timeSheetEntry.workTime.append(updateTimeSheet)

                print("save successful")
            }
        }catch{
            print("error saving Context")
        }
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Your code snippet creates a new `EmployeeTimeSheet` object and adds it to your Realm. Why is it surprising that doing this twice creates two separate objects? Nowhere in your code do you attempt to _update_ an existing object.

Comment: "I am trying to update a specific item in a realm model. "  You say you want to update a singular item.  What is an item?  The title says you want to update multiple columns.  How do you get the specif record (the row or record) to edit?

Comment: I am not surprised that it creates two separate objects what I am asking is how can I specify at a later time to just edit the timeOut on the specific "date" or "row" and leave everything else committed to the database the same as the first commit, using the same view controller.

Comment: You need to make use of primary key. Specify some column which is unique as primary key and based on it you can update existing record.

Comment: Updates are well documented. Is this approach not working? https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys

Comment: No, I have implemented primary keys and I think I modified my code to accommodate, but it is still not working, I know it is something simple that I am doing wrong but I just can't see it. I updated the above code to reflect the primary key.